# Responsive tabs bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to make my tabs with bootstrap responsive tabs. Did exactly what is says here http://openam.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/ and when i click on tabs, notnihg happens, it doesn't go to clicked tab. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container marketing">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" id="myTab">
<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content responsive">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...content...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...content...</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...content...</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
fakewaffle.responsiveTabs(['xs', 'sm']);
})(jQuery);
</script>
</div><!-- /.container -->

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsive-tabs.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http//:jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rQZym/ sorry, here it is.

Comment: You need to include all the relevant script files in your fiddle.  It won't work at all without them, as can bee seen in the browser console.

Comment: I have included all relevant files, added them to external resources. I have all of them and more included in on my project, but it is the same as this one on jsfiddle when i run it, i have tabs and it doesn't open any other than first tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Bootstrap version `>= 3.0` not `2.3.2`.

Also. you're not include the `responsive-tabs.js` in your fiddle wich results in this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fakewaffle is not defined
```

So you need to include: `jQuery` , `bootstrap css and js >=3.0` ,  `responsive-tabs.js`

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rQZym/3/)**

Comment: I am just seeing this, try to resize tabs in that jsfiddle, when it is on big screen it is not working, it is working only when tabs are one beneath another, why?

Comment: You need add another jQuery code to show the tab. This is fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eQJME/